# What's the name of this webdesign element/trick?

Tags: html, css

Surfing the web I see websites with a floating design element. But I cannot find how it is called. Does somebody know the name of the following element:

At the adobe website there is a yellow box with the question "Was this helpful?". When you scroll down it stays at the top of the screen.
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/fireworks/learning_guide/design/design_guide_pt4.html

Where can I find more information about it? Thanks.

Comment: you might want to look this [link to learn more](http://css-tricks.com/scrollfollow-sidebar/), work with the same approach but if you don't want to apply the scroll affect just use fixed position.

Answer (score 2):

There's a plugin called Sticky sidebar doing this.

[Article](http://www.marcofolio.net/webdesign/create_a_sticky_sidebar_or_box.html) and [Demonstration](http://demo.marcofolio.net/create_a_sticky_sidebar_or_box/)

Comment: Thanks, and the stickt sidebar is not possible with CSS3?

Comment: @Paul without having looked at the demo, try `position: fixed`

Comment: @JanDvorak That's not enough : it's not really sticky : it just doesn't disappear when you scroll.

Comment: @Paul You have to use css+javascript. You can't do this in pure CSS.

Comment: For me, the box switches between `fixed` and normal based on the scroll position.

Comment: If you want it be responsive you have to use jquery.

Comment: Searching for sticky sidebar did help! I will try if I can get it done with CSS styles like: position absolute, z-index so it hides below my normal sidebar and appears when the user has scrolled down.  - EDIT: or is the jquery cleaner? I never used it and I always tried to stay away from JS.

Comment: @RosieAggabao This can be done without jQuery. jQuery does simplify things a little, though.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [Sticky jQuery plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/sticky/). It should do what you want.

Comment: Please don't answer with just a link. Especially when the page you link to doesn't even have a working demo.

Comment: and what do you expect me to do about it?

Answer (score 1):

Its called sticky sidebar.

[Here](http://www.htmldrive.net/items/show/1053/jQuery-Sticky-scrolling-Sidebar) is the link for demo plus code go through it.

Answer (score 1):

It uses the simple css style `position:fixed` to ensure the element remains where it is in the viewport when the page is scrolled.

However the link you gave expands on it in that the `position:fixed` style is only applied once you scroll a certain distance down the page. The easiest way to achieve it is to use jQuery to change the class of the element when the user scrolls down to it.

Here is a function that can change the class accordingly.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
// Check the initial Position of the Sticky Element
    var stickyElementTop = $('#stickyElement').offset().top;

// Apply the CSS class if you scroll past
    $(window).scroll(function(){
            if( $(window).scrollTop() > stickyElementTop ) {
                    $('#stickyElement').addClass('sticky');                      
                } else {
                    $('#stickyElement').removeClass('sticky');                        
            }
    });
}
```

And then use css

```
#stickyElement{
    position:absolute/relative/whatever;
    }
.sticky{
    position:fixed!important;
    }
```